# ANDROID: I want to run a method everyday at 13.00

Tags: java, android, service, alarm

I have an Android App
In my main activity I have a method, which is started when the user clicks a button.

I want to automate this method to run once a day

The method pulls in information and sends it to an local (phone) database.

I am unsure of the alarm service code.

Do I need to put my method into a service and call that at a specified time?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your method to run every single day regardless of whether the application is open or not. In that case you will need to implement a service. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html